# display 'welcome " customer_name"' at the top of the magento site

Tags: login, header

when customer login to site, it should display "welcome customer" at top of the site.

assume customer will login to site. after customer login, in top of the site there

should be a some message to welcome customer.

how to display welcome " customer_name" at the top of the site.

please help me to find solution.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that is what you are looking for:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416553/current-user-in-magento

```
public function getWelcome()
{
    if (empty($this->_data['welcome'])) {
        if (Mage::app()->isInstalled() && Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
            $this->_data['welcome'] = $this->__('Welcome, %s!', Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getName());
        } else {
            $this->_data['welcome'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/header/welcome');
        }
    }

    return $this->_data['welcome'];
}
```

So it looks like Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer() will get your current logged in customer ;)

Comment: hi, can you please tell me which code i have to replace by " Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()"

Comment: Did you check under "app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Header.php" if you have the function getWelcome() like the one above?

Comment: yes, i saw that header.php and welcome message.....

Comment: yes and does your function look the same than this one above?

Comment: exactly same code is there....

Comment: yes so it works for you or not when you are logged in?

Comment: we are using 1.9 version, but it's not displaying in http://demo.kidsdial.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21182/discussion-between-thomas-and-user9434334345).

Comment: thanks a lot , there was a welcome message was missing in header.phtml